# How can I override a setter from a SuperClass in Swift with Xcode 6.3 Beta2?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, overriding, uicollectionviewcell

My SuerClass is `UICollectionViewCell`which has a property:

```
var selected: Bool
```

My class is

```
MyClass : UICollectionViewCell {

  func setSelected(selected: Bool) { 
    super.selected = selected
    // do something
 }

}
```

The former worked well in Xcode 6.2 but in Xcode 6.3Beta2 it raises an error:

```
Method 'setSelected' with Objective-C selector 'setSelected:' conflicts with setter for 'selected' from superclass 'UICollectionViewCell' with the same Objective-C selector
```

**How can I fix this to work with Xcode 6.3 beta2?**

Edit:  I also tried:

```
  override func setSelected(selected: Bool) { 
    super.selected = selected
    // do something
 }
```

This leads to the error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: Did you use the `overrides` keyword?  Did you try overriding it as a property?

Comment: @nhgrif ``override`` does not work see my edit.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If all we want it do some extra functionality after the `selected` property as been set, we can simply override to add a property observer:

```
override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if self.selected {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Updated Answer for Swift 5:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if self.isSelected {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

If we care about what the previous value of `selected` was, we can access it via `oldValue`:

```
didSet {
    if self.selected == oldValue {
        return
    }
    // do something
}
```

Updated Answer for Swift 5:

```
didSet {
    if self.isSelected == oldValue {
        return
    }
    // do something
}
```

And don't forget, we can use `willSet` as well if we need to do something just before the value is changed.

---

I was curious what would happen when we've got a large hierarchy of classes each adding their own stuff in `willSet` and `didSet` property observers, so I created the following test:

```
class ClassA {
    var _foo: Int = 0
    var foo: Int {
        set(newValue) {
            println("Class A setting foo")
            self._foo = newValue
        }
        get {
            return self._foo
        }
    }
}

class ClassB: ClassA {
    override var foo: Int {
        willSet {
            println("Class B will set foo")
        }
        didSet {
            println("Class B did set foo")
        }
    }
}

class ClassC: ClassB {
    override var foo: Int {
        willSet {
            println("Class C will set foo")
        }
        didSet {
            println("Class C did set foo")
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if we create an object of `ClassC` and set its `foo` property:

```
var c: ClassC = ClassC()  
c.foo = 42
```

We get the following output:

```
Class C will set foo
Class B will set foo
Class A setting foo
Class B did set foo
Class C did set foo
```

So, it's important to note a few things from this...

- A child class's `willSet` is called **before** its parent's `willSet`.
- A child class's `didSet` is called **after** its parent's `didSet`.
- Creating an override for the sake of adding property observers **does not** replace any property observers in the parent classes.

The first two points make a bit of sense.  And actually, this makes property observers much more appealing.  Effectively, Swift forces our hand into going up and down the heirarchy in the appropriate manner and nicely splits it out into two separate methods.  Swift also prevents us (I believe) from overriding a parent class's property, but also still lets us observe changes to that property--this is much better than Objective-C's approach.

But the third point is probably the most important.  Be careful--you can easily get bogged down in a massive heirarchy of `didSet` and `willSet` code that's slowing down what should be a pretty quick process: setting a property's value.