# how to change the label colour in collection view cell by click

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have one collection view with some cells. Inside my cells I have one label to show a list of country names. And on every click of each cell labels I will display some data in table view below my collection view.

When I press any cell label I need to turn that label's text red. And other label names should be black.

How to do that? I have tried the code below, but when I select any label name in that cell all the cell labels are turning red.

How do I fix this?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        if let cell = collectionView1.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

            var label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel


            label!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label doesn't update because you need to refresh cells. So best solution I could offer you - change your label color in `setSelected` method in your **custom cell's class**

Edit:

---

```
override var setSelected(selected: bool) {
    if (selected) { 
       self.youLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {
       self.youLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

This is example of function in your custom class. Sorry, if there are mistakes - answered from iPhone

Comment: i am new to iOS.Can you give me some code example .That what should i have to do in my custom cell class

Comment: Ok. That's pretty simple.

Comment: Yes i am getting error under `bool` in this line `func setSelected(selected: bool)`

Comment: Try to refer to this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049238/how-can-i-override-a-setter-from-a-superclass-in-swift-with-xcode-6-3-beta2

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**:

In your cell class:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        label.textColor = .red
    }
}
```

And from the delegate class:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.isSelected = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i created with your code, it is working to me. but i think, it is better to create with custom collectionview cell.

[demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i27n6eq2pkodp4g/collection.zip?dl=0)

Comment: The same thing what  have written in my question post code know.Like that only your solution is also there.But what i need is when ever i press one label it have to turn to red color.And if i select other label , the existing selected label should turn to black colour.Means that only the selected cell label alone have o show red colour.

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let label = cell!.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel
        label?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

Comment: so i think you need to turn back label color in collectionview. Hope to help this one. :)